# iOS11 paged scroll view suddenly is scrollable vertically

Tags: uiscrollview, ios11

I have an app which uses EMPageViewController to display a set of onboarding slides. My understanding is that the underlying scroll view is using paged mode to display slides.

Upon update to iOS11, I see that suddenly the slides follow the finger, so they are draggable and bounce up and down. I expect paged scroll view to be scrollable horizontally only.

**How can I restrict paged scroll view to horizontal scrolling only in iOS11 ?**

I tried this but it did not work

```
 pageViewController.scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fixes the issue:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *)
{
    self.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
}
```

> The behavior for determining the adjusted content offsets. This
>   property specifies how the safe area insets are used to modify the
>   content area of the scroll view.

contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior is new from iOS 11 > and the default value is automatic.

> Content is always adjusted vertically when the scroll view is the
>   content view of a view controller that is currently displayed by a
>   navigation or tab bar controller. If the scroll view is horizontally
>   scrollable, the horizontal content offset is also adjusted when there
>   are nonzero safe area insets.

Which made some of my UIScrollView scroll more than they were excepted to.